# Spring 5 Webclient Handle 500 error and modify the response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Spring app acting as a passthrough from one app to another, making a http request and returning a result to the caller using `WebClient`. If the client http call returns a 500 internal server error I want to be able to catch this error and update the object that gets returned rather than re-throwing the error or blowing up the app.

This is my Client:

```
 final TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
    .doOnConnected(connection -> connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout))
        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(writeTimeout)));

this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .filter(logRequest())
    .filter(logResponse())
    .filter(errorHandler())
    .build();
```

And this is my error handler. I've commented where I want to modify the result, where `ResponseDto` is the custom object that is returned from the client call happy path

```
public static ExchangeFilterFunction errorHandler(){
return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
  ResponseDto resp = new ResponseDto();
  if(nonNull(clientResponse.statusCode()) && clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()){
    //this is where I want to modify the response
    resp.setError("This is the error");
  }
  //not necessarily the correct return type here
  return Mono.just(clientResponse);
});
}
```

How can I achieve this? I can't find any tutorials or any information in the docs to help explain it.

Disclaimer, I'm new to webflux. We're only starting to look at reactive programming

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you take a look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/ ?

Comment: No, isn't that for an api gateway? I can see the WebClientWriteResponseFilter class - is that what you're referring to?